# Bluemix(cloud foundry) Manifest Variables

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, manifest, cloud-foundry

I have a web-application that is hosted on two environments one is DEV one is PROD, the DEV environment has _DEV and _UAT instances, which we are currently testings. The issue is this - in both DEV and PROD app name is the same, but for UAT it has _UAT extension. Since changing the manifest every time is not an option, do you know how can I set up and use variables so that bluemix can see that if _UAT is the environment, use this name and these settings?

Here is a snap of our manifest with names changed:

```
applications:
 path: .
  memory: 256M
  instances: 3
  domain:  bm.devfg.com
  buildpack: sdk-for-nodejs
  name: AppName (in UAT this should say AppName_UAT)
  host: AppName
  disk_quota: 1024M
services:
  - dynatracesaasnodejs
  - postgresunixdb
env:
  NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: "0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used full blown substitution of the entire manifest file in some of my projects.  As part of the preparations for build and deployment, just do a simple copy of the proper manifest file.  In one of my old projects I had four different manifest files: manifest.yml, manifest_PROD.yml, Manifest_DEV.yml, and manifest_TEST.yml.  As part of the deployment and build script (using the [Continuous Delivery services](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/continuous-delivery)), just copy the appropriate manifest file to manifest.yml before starting deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using [variable substitution](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#multi-manifests) for your manifest file. With that your appname would be read from the environment or passed in from another configuration file:

```
name: ((appname))
```

Comment: I understand that I can somehow make it look at the environment, but I fail to find the actual steps required to do so. Changing the manifest is the easy part, but how and where would I tell my app that it has to look at the environments? On the side note - we are not using CLI to push, we use hooks from Jenkins to UCD, so cf push command will not work.

Comment: That was not part of your question... Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191898/specific-configuration-per-space-in-manifest-yml